# how to get bracets around asp:label when using: Text='<%# Eval("filmProd") %>

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Hello how can i get brackets around my output from: 
`asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("filmProd") %>' runat="server" ID="filmProd" />`

now the output is: 2016

i want it to be: (2016)

I guess its bad code to put the whole label in bracets like this? `(asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("filmProd") %>' runat="server" ID="filmProd" />)`

Comment: Text='<%# String.Format("({0})"), Eval("filmProd")) %>'

Comment: Why would it be bad code?  If it's view logic and it works...  As long as the pattern is valid for all of your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`DataBinder.Eval()` method contains an overload that supports passing in a formatting string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2d76z3ck(v=vs.110).aspx) that you can use to handle scenarios like this :

```
Text='<%# Eval("filmProd", "({0})") %>'
```

Alternatively, you could just use the [`String.Format()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) method and pass the result of your `Eval()` call in as a parameter :

```
Text='<%# String.Format("({0})",Eval("filmProd")) %>'
```